# Ng-animate on subdirective doesn't run

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, css-animations, ng-animate

I'm attempting to animate a subdirective that gets generated with an `ng-repeat` inside a directive. I've managed to successfully animate one of my `ng-repeats` with a `ng-stagger` included so i know the library is working.

For some reason the class of `.group` animates to enter and leave but the `ng-stagger` is completely ignored as well, however the `.menu-group-item` never gets an animation, even without animating `.group`.

Currently I have my directive set up as such,

#### The directive `menu_items` repeats through its attribute `groups`

```
ul.menus.fat
  li.group(ng-repeat='group in groups' ng-class-even="'alt-row'")
```

#### Then it loops through each `group.items` passing them to a subdirective

```
ul.menu-group-items(ng-show='group.items && group.items.length > 0')
  li.menu-group-item(ng-repeat='item in group.items track by item.id' ng-class-even="'alt-row'")
    menu-item(item='item')
```

### CSS

```
ul.menus .menu-group-item {
  color: #81807e;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0 -10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}


ul.menus .group.ng-enter,
ul.menus .group.ng-leave,
ul.menus .menu-group-item.ng-enter
ul.menus .menu-group-item.ng-leave {
   -webkit-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
  -moz-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
  -ms-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
  -o-transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
  transition: 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

ul.menus .group.ng-leave.ng-leave-active,
ul.menus .menu-group-item.ng-leave.ng-leave-active,
ul.menus .group.ng-enter,
ul.menus .menu-group-item.ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

ul.menus .group.ng-enter.ng-enter-active,
ul.menus .menu-group-item.ng-enter.ng-enter-active,
ul.menus .menu-group-item.ng-leave,
ul.menus .group.ng-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

ul.menus .menu-group-item.ng-enter-stagger,
ul.menus .menu-group-item.ng-enter-stagger,
ul.menus .menu-group-item.ng-leave-stagger,
ul.menus .group.ng-leave-stagger,
ul.menus .group.ng-move-stagger,
ul.menus .group.ng-move-stagger {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 10s;
  transition-delay: 10s;
  -webkit-transition-duration:0;
  transition-duration:0;
}
```

Why does this not animate and why does the animation that does work the stagger doesn't? My ideal objective is to only animate the `.menu-group-item` items since there part of the `.group`.

Comment: I had provided an [answer earlier here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25287517/cant-trigger-animation-on-nested-ngrepeat/25289240#25289240) relating to getting the children animated, probably yours is also similar? Try adding `ng-animate-children` attribute on the parent

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work :( `li.group(ng-repeat='group in groups' ng-class-even="'alt-row'" ng-animate-children)`

Comment: Can you prepare a demo in a plunkr?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/4TSOri7CkWLc1XoLbCjD?p=preview sorry if its not exact it was a bit of a pain to create haha

Comment: I've managed to solve the children not animating, it was due to jade getting changed from `ng-animate-children` to `ng-animate-children='ng-animate-children'` But still the `ng-enter-stagger` or `ng-leave-stagger` has yet to take effect for some reason.

Comment: Yeah it looks like it is fine. I noticed it takes a while when clicked on reload.. is that what your issue is?

Comment: @PSL if you notice in the plukr it doesn't animate the `.groups` still.  Now it only animates the children